# I am trying to find at least one digit in a string but i am getting an error below

Tags: syntax-error

I am trying to find at least one digit in a string by using regular expression but i dont know why it is not working

```
const password = 'sadrFeff4ss5';
const isExistsNumber = /^(?=*[0-9])/.test(password);
```

const isExistsNumber = /^(?=.*[0-9])/.test(password);
Here the regex pattern /^(?=*[0-9])/ should find one number from the sring 'sadrFeff4ss5' but i am getting an syntax error
Module parse failed: Invalid regular expression: /^(?=*[0-9])/: Nothing to
repeat (53:28);
I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Is there a reason for not just looking for a digit, with \d?

Comment: you are using a positive lookahead assertion `(?=`starting with ´*´ .. that's a quantifier but you didn't specify of what!! plus you have the correct regex below in your question `(?=.*[0-9])`... not even the effort to double check

Comment: Just remove the anchor character ^. It means that what follows it     must be at the beginning of the word.